# PHP 7 mysqli_real_escape_string() Error

Tags: php, warnings, php-7

I update php 5 to php 7 quite recently.so that when i run the project it gives following error.

**Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Duplicate - Copy (2)\general.php on line 5**

Here is the Code.

```
<?php
function sanitize($data){   
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
}
?>
```

then i recoded connection like this.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', "");
```

can anyone help me please!

Comment: Umm.. _expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given_ what does that tell you?  Did you look at the manual???

Comment: When i use php 5 version .code works fine,but now it says like that

Comment: You mean you had warnings turned off in php 5?

Comment: @Dasun You're not using PHP5 and `mysql_*` anymore so read the documentation for PHP7's `mysqli_*` because it is different. Old `string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )` vs new `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )` is different for a reason.

Comment: @jeroen This is likely a migration effort from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That's possible, but with 1 line of PDO and 1 line of mysqli it could be anything...

Comment: i change code like this  `function sanitize($db, $data){
 
 return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
?>`  So error was gone

Comment: But Now problem is here     ** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() ** what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)?

The first parameter needs to be your connection object.

You also however you appear to be mixing and matching PDO and mysqli functions.

Pick one or the other.